# C#: Why does safe casting (as) return overridden methods instead of base methods?

Tags: c#, casting

Looking at how the `as` keyword works in C#, I can see that it allows for casting where explicit casting (i.e. using brackets) prevents compilation.

However In the code below I find that if I override a method in a derived class, and then safe cast as the base class, that the overridden method in the derived class still executes. Why is this? I was expecting the method as defined on the base class to execute instead.

```
class Base
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }

    public string OtherMethod()
    {
        return "Other method";
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Derived class";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Derived d = new Derived();
        Base b = new Base();

        System.Console.WriteLine(b.ToString()); // Base
        System.Console.WriteLine(d.ToString()); // Derived class
        System.Console.WriteLine((d as Base).ToString()); // Derived class => WHY IS THIS?
        System.Console.WriteLine((d as Base).OtherMethod()); // Other method
        // System.Console.WriteLine((Base)d.OtherMethod()); // --- prevents compilation

        // As noted in the comments, this works
        System.Console.WriteLine(((Base)d).OtherMethod()); // Other method

        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: The line marked as "prevents compilation" isn't failing because of the type of cast. It's failing because you're trying to cast the *return value* from `OtherMethod`. `((Base)d).OtherMethod()` should compile just fine.

Comment: You are trying to break the polymorphism feature of object-oriented programming.  Luckily you can't do that, that would be bad.

Comment: It calls the overridden method because the method is *overridden*. That's the whole point of overriding methods, so that they get called instead of the base method.

Comment: "Why is this?" The as operator doesn't change the actual type of the object in memory. It just returns a reference to this object (or a null reference if the cast fails).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only time when a cast to a base-class is *required* and will result in the execution of a different method is when you have a case of *shadowing*.

Shadowing occurs when a derived class implements a method of the same name as a method in a base class<sup>1</sup> and, explicitly, this is not an `override`. Usually, these are marked, instead, with the keyword `new`. If you have an instance of the derived class but wish to invoke the base class member, you need to cast it to that base class (or to any intermediate class in the inheritance chain that doesn't itself shadow the method in question)

In the absence of shadowing, any method invocation always uses the most derived method, based on the runtime type of the object, not the variable's declared type.

Shadowing is usually best avoided, however.

---

<sup>1</sup>Not necessarily the direct base class - anywhere within the chain of inheritance back to `object`.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at this (http://shadowing-in-csharp.blogspot.co.za/2012/10/shadowing-what-when-and-why.html), the time to use shadowing is when you want your derived class with the same method name to return a different type? Is there another use case?

Comment: @ZachSmith - I'd generally argue that the time to use shadowing is *never*. For varying return types, I'd generally look to a generic-based solution. Or alternate names. The only place where shadowing is inevitable revolves around a hierarchy with different authors; when the base class authors later introduce a method name that inheritors have already used. That's why shadowing is technically an opt-in feature. You don't *have* to use `new` to cause shadowing to occut, but it will raise a warning.

Answer (score 0):

That is just how inheritance and polymorphism works in C#. The `as` operator does a safe cast only, but internally its still a `Derived`. It just changes it so that the compiler knows it has the right types. With your types, the casting is unnecessary. This just works:

```
 Base d = new Derived();
```

This will still call the virtual methods overridden by `Derived`.

As for the explicit cast, its failing because it has a lower precedence than the other operators on that expression. The whole right hand side is evaluated first, then the cast. Essentially, this is what you are telling the compiler.

```
 string result = d.OtherMethod();
 Base result2 = (Base)d;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can hopefully help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx

> Base classes may define and implement virtualmethods, and derived classes can override them, which means they provide their own definition and implementation. **At run-time, when client code calls the method, the CLR looks up the run-time type of the object, and invokes that override of the virtual method**. Thus in your source code you can call a method on a base class, and cause a derived class's version of the method to be executed.

In your case you're calling the `Object.ToString()` virtual method, and the appropriate override is selected during runtime.